# Export Jacoco's coverage report in XML format to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module project and I am using JaCoCo plugin to generate coverage reports. I followed this [blog](http://janejieblog.blogspot.com/2017/12/code-coverage-jacoco-with-maven-multi.html) to create a new module(let's call it **project-coverage**) and then added the dependencies there and then use the **report-aggregate** goal of jacoco to create the aggregated report.

At the end of the build I have an XML file under **project-coverage/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml**

How can I take this XML and export it into Jenkins? I know there is a plugin support for Jacoco in Jenkins but I am not sure how can I use this XML report and not exec files to report the coverage in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

> I know there is a plugin support for Jacoco in Jenkins but I am not sure how can I use this XML report and not exec files to report the coverage in Jenkins.

According to https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/integrations.html there are at least two plugins for Jenkins. And according to the documentation of these plugins

- https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco/ consumes `exec`
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/code-coverage-api/ consumes `XML`